# how to convert an arraylist<object> to String and reconvert it to arraylist<object>

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I am trying to convert my arrayList to a string for a while and convert the string to arrayList because i want to insert the string into a listView and this string contain some random /n , here is the code:

```
ArrayList<msg> per = new ArrayList<msg>();
String t;
t="................................./n........";
msm = new msg();
test();
per.add(msm);
MonAdapter adapter = new MonAdapter(this, R.layout.list, per);
```

Comment: do you want to slip the string into many substrings basing on the separator /n

Comment: Don't. What you want is to display the objects as they are, which means to have to enhance the adapter to be able to display them correctly. Like the custom layout in https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview for example.

Comment: @haceneabdessamed yes effectively

Comment: @zapl i did not unsderstand what you have said

Comment: Don't change the `ArrayList<SomeObject>` to `ArrayList<String>`. Change the adapter so it can display `SomeObject` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use a `ArrayList<String>`?
or a `ArrayList<Object>` and give the Object a String variable holding the data you want to display?

so you can call `array.get(position).dataIWantInString()`;

EDIT:

you can create a object like this:

```
public class MyObject {

  public String myData;

  public MyObject(String data){
    myData = data
  }
}
```

if you create a `ArrayList<MyObject>` you dont have to convert the array to get the value you want.

you add a new MyObject by calling `myArray.add(new MyObject("hello"));`
and can use `MyObject obj = myArray.get(positionInArray)` to retreive the object.
and finally you can call `obj.myData` to retreive your string

Comment: didn't understood you

Comment: you wanted to show strings in a list right? you can also use the above code to create a ArrayList<String> by creating a for loop: for(int i=o;i<myObjects.size(); i++){ stringarraylist.add(myObjects.get(i).myData); }

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            list.add("Item " + i);
        }
```

ArrayList to String:

```
String string = list.toString();
```

String to ArrayList:

```
String[] array = list.split(",");
List<String> listAgain = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```